# highchart : create stock chart

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I'm creating a stock chart in highcharts.

But it gives an error in .ts file

i.e

> ERROR in src/app/dionaea/dionaea.component.ts(313,23): error TS2339:
>   Property 'stockChart' does not exist on type 'Static'.

Can anyone have solution of this error.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('conPerDateGraph', {
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'AAPL',
        data: data,
        tooltip: {
            valueDecimals: 2
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

highstock.d.ts currently doesn't define any exports as such, thats the reason your getting complie error while using StockChart property. 
Modify highstock.d.ts to define extra exports as shown below:

```
declare var Highstock: __Highstock.Static;
export = Highstock;
export as namespace Highstock;
```

In your my TS file you can use it like this:

```
import * as Highstock from "highcharts/highstock";
```